# How can I achieve this electronic 'growl' sound?

Tags: synthesizer, electronic-music

My primary example is Scream by Bignic, where the sound I'm talking about is used for the lead (begins 40 seconds in).

Comment: Probably some form of filter sweep that starts off closed then opens then closes again.

Comment: Are you talking about the vocoder kind of sound ?

Comment: As @No'amNewman wrote, it comes from filters that imitate human voice. But the question, as written now, asking to identify instrument/equipment/technique, is off-topic.

Comment: @Tom yes thats the one

Comment: @user1079505 can you suggest what those filters would be?

Comment: To make things sound like human, this can be of some help : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant, you will see that you need at least two filters..

Comment: Note to close voters, this does not seem to ask for a specific plugin but how to achieve this kind of sound, which is more a technical point of view and I would argue is on topic

Comment: @Tom It's [been discussed](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2963/our-on-topic-page-currently-says-that-identifying-a-technique-is-off-topic). As I see it, there's a spectrum between "give me tips on flatpicking" (a "how-to" technique question that many might have) and "help me duplicate this specific sound" (more likely to be one-off). Of course, then there's also the person who's never heard flatpicking before, and is phrasing the first kind of question as the second...

Comment: To make it a good on-topic question, I'd suggest the following: 1. Add more description to what do you want to achieve, rather just a link, so the question is unambiguous and searchable, 2. Write what have you tried. This will help to understand what specific problem is there to solve.

Comment: It will help to know what tools you have available.  The way to get there with a plugin is different from the approach with a standalone analog synth.  @Tom is correct that you need two filters in either case.  Probably an oscillator sync as well.

Comment: Sounds like a talk box or vocoder to me - a bit too vocal for a formant filter

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yep, I thought of a vocoder too. Maybe fed from a very distorted clavinet sound?